# Prove the decidability of an enumerable set. A and B are enumerable, C is decidable.

Tags: computability, turing-machines, decidability

Sets A and B are enumerable, C is decidable. $A$ $\subseteq$ $C$ $\subseteq$ $A$ $\cup$ $B$. $A$ $\cap$ $B$ = $\emptyset $.Prove that A is decidable too

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know so far?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it's quite hard to answer your question. It's a new field of math to me. It started in my university 3 weeks ago, so we don't know hard theorems.  Some basic facts anddefinitions.

Comment: Well, what does it mean to show that $A$ is decidable?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it's about to prove that we have algorithm - "blackbox" which takes numbers from $N$ and returns 1 if this element in $A$ else returns 0

Comment: Ok; let $n \in \mathbb N$. $C$ is decidable; thus, if the answer to "is $n \in C$ ?" is No, then $n \notin A$.

Comment: And what does enumerable mean? Put these in the question. I know for sure that decidable has two (equivalent) definitions, and the answers people give will be different depending on which definition is used.

Comment: If the answer is Yes, then $n \in A \cup B$. Start enumerating $A$ and $B$ simultaneously...

Comment: thanks everyone! I'm so glad to see a solution of this task!

Comment: This is wrong. You need stronger hypotheses, namely, that $A$ and $B$ are **computably** enumerable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an algorithm to determine if a number $n$ is in $A$ or not. First of all, ask if $n\in C$: if $n\not\in C$, then $n\not\in A$ since $A\subseteq C$. If instead $n\in C$, we proceed as follows: we ask at the same time if $n\in A$ and if $n\in B$. Notice that this question will be answered in a finite amount of time, since $C\subseteq A\cup B$, and exactly one of the two questions will have positive answer, since $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Hence, $A$ is decidable.

Comment: The OP did not say that $A$ and $B$ are recursively (or "computably") enumerable, only that they are "enumerable", so I don't think this works.

Comment: @bof Can you please explain why this doesn't works? I'm new in theory of computability and e.t.c

Comment: @bof you're right, I answered assuming that what the OP meant was that $A$ and $B$ are computably enumerable, since this would then become a fairly standard exercise about basic computability theory. Michael, can you please clarify what you mean by enumerable?